# Best algorithm for time series prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I would like to ask you some suggestions about a time series prediction problem. In particular, I have to predict on a daily basis the **total water demand** in a certain area, creating a model based on 4 CVSs files containing:

- water demand in aggregated form (time series with daily granularity, 2 years data)
- amount of water entering the area's cistern (time series with daily granularity, 2 years data)
- amount of water leaving the area's cistern (time series with daily granularity, 2 years data)
- water request from 4,000 measurements points across the area (time series with daily granularity, 2 years data).

In your opinion, what is the best model for having a good prediction of the water demand in the area, using the available data and features? I can only think of LSTMs or MLP, I don't know if something like ARIMA or (SARIMA) could be useful in this case, seeing that I have many features but not many days.
Thank you in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forecasting is inevitably a domain-specific problem because you can often make better decisions about model and methods when you know something about the system or process you are trying to forecast.

There are quite a few academic papers on forecasting domestic water demand which you could look at if you have access:

E.g.

- [Demand Forecasting for Water Distribution Systems by Chen and Boccelli (2014)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187770581400040X)
- [Urban Water Demand Forecasting: Review of Methods and Models by Donkor et al (2014)](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/%28ASCE%29WR.1943-5452.0000314)
- [Predicting water demand: a review of the methods employed and future possibilities by de Souza Groppo et. al (2019)](https://iwaponline.com/ws/article-abstract/19/8/2179/69623/Predicting-water-demand-a-review-of-the-methods)

I'm not an expert in this domain so you should probably wait for someone who is to answer the question but I think using an [auto-regressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) (e.g. ARIMA), as you have suggested, is a good start because demand is essentially due to aggregate human activity which is inherently driven by daily / weekly routines, and seasonal effects.

There are various routines to fit such models to data.  Jason Brownlee has a nice tutorial [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/) using Python's statsmodels.tsa package.

You could also see what people have used for residential energy consumption forecasting as the problem is probably very similar to water demand forecasting.